# Using the properties of the vector triple product and the scalar triple product,prove that

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

$$
(\bar{a}\times \bar{b})\cdot \left(   (\bar{b}+\bar{c})\times (\bar{c}+\bar{a})   \right) = 0
$$

I tried to solve this but always  stuck

Comment: You can take a better picture, and rotate the image.

Comment: I post a new picture now you can see

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I post it on answers panel

Answer (score 0):

I have tried several times several ways but I couldn't approach the solution.this is one way i tried to solve this(https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2hpE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This is false for arbitrary vectors $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$. Perhaps there is a certain relationship between the vectors you forgot to mention? As a counterexample,
take $\vec{a}=(1,0,0), \vec{b}=(0,1,0), \vec{c}=(1,0,0)$.Then
$$\vec a\times \vec b=(0,0,1)\\
\vec b+\vec c=(1,1,0)\\
\vec c+\vec a=(2,0,0)\\
(\vec b+\vec c)\times(\vec c+\vec a)=(0,0,-2)\\
(\vec a\times\vec b)\cdot\bigl((\vec b+\vec c)\times(\vec c+\vec a)\bigr)=-2 $$

Comment: There is no such a relation as i think this problem is wrong sorry for the inconvenience